# Efficient way to call Update, Start etc on all 'base' classes from multi-inherited class?

Tags: c#, oop, unity-game-engine

I am attempting to create a 2D game in Unity. Essentially, there are multiple types of 'agents': enemies and players. Programmatically, both classes 'enemy' and 'player' derive from the agent class. Then, there are different types of enemies (such as flying, ground enemies, etc).

My issue is that I need to call the Update function on all derivatives of an enemy. This is because there is code that needs to run for **all** enemies, and other code that should only run for **some** enemies - **all** enemies need to know where the player is, but only **some** enemies need to fly.

I read somewhere that you can use the new keyword, then call the base update function. However, with multiple levels of subclasses this seems inefficient and clunky as you have to state "new" for each new instance.

Is there any better way to call Update, Start and FixedUpdate (functions that are automatically called) than how I have implemented this below? Thanks in advance.

```cs
public abstract class Agent : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Start(){
        // Run start code for all types of 'players', including AI
    }
}

public class Enemy : Agent
{
    public new void Start()
    {
        base.Start();
        // Run start code specific to all enemies
    }
}

public class WalkerEnemy : Enemy 
{
    public new void Start()
    {
        base.Start();
        // Run start code specific to walking enemies ONLY
        // Invoking Enemy.Start() will result in a call of Agent.Start() as well
    }
}
```

Thank You for your help. Whilst I would call myself 'intermediate' in my programming skills, I doubt my object oriented knowledge is as fluent as it could be. So if there is some fundamental idea that I am missing, please let me know :)

Comment: Did you try Invoke/IENumerator?

Comment: It sounds like you are describing the call super anti-pattern.

Comment: Suggest you use compoents to combine your enemy , use compoenst is more expandability way :)

Comment: @Ginxxx can you please elaborate? Maybe add an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, when using inheritance structure, you usually want to avoid using the new keyword. Instead you mark the methods of the base class which you want to change for inheriting classes with the virtual keyword (or abstract if the baseclass does not contain code). That way you can re-use the code in the baseclass or even remove it all together.

An approach which may be even better in your case is to make an abstract method which you call in your baseclass start method. That way, inheriting classes MUST implement the method. This will be forced by the compiler.

Example:

```
public abstract class Agent : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start(){
        // Your code needed for all inheriting classes here.

        // Call the abstract method which is defined on inheriting classes
        OnStarting();
    }

    protected abstract void OnStarting();
}

public class Enemy : Agent
{
    protected override OnStarting()
    {
        // Your enemy code here.
    }
}

public class WalkerEnemy : Enemy 
{
    protected override OnStarting()
    {
        base.OnStarting(); // Call the code from the Enemy class
        // Your walker enemy code here.
    }
}
```

Also as you might see, I made your `Start` method private. Since Unity calls this by itself. You do not want to call this yourself from anywhere in your application. The `OnStarting` methods are marked as protected, because they should only exist/ be used in the scope of this inheritance tree.

Comment: Keep in mind, that the WalkerEnemy.OnStarting overwrites the Enemy.OnStarting without calling the base implementation. This might lead to unexpected behavior. I would suggest to add base.OnStarting() to the beginning of WalkerEnemy.OnStarting.

Comment: VisualStudio auto-completes the call to the base-implementation for virtual methods. That's helpful!